# Getting a PHISH/Zmate.omna detection by Avira when I refresh my page, but online website scanners are showing that the page is clean

Tags: malware, php, apache, html

I'm getting a PHISH/Zmate.omna detection by Avira when I refresh my page, showing that it was put in the chrome cache. But I tried several online website/url scanners, and they are all showing that the page is clean.

Is it a false positive? Or do I need to use something else to detect it?

Comment: are you sure it isn't a browser plugin that put extra content into the site?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the designate website will not help very much if it is a malvertisement(Malware advertisement) campaign coming from third party javascript inside the web page.

You should check the AV report to see whether it capture URL that download the phishing contents.  That will tell you which URL is really the culprits.

Comment: Exactly, thank you. Most malvertising check the browser environment and don't do anything malicious when ran in a sandbox